# Angular 10 Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'option'

Tags: angular

I know this is a very popular error, and there are a lot of answers already posted, but none of the solutions seem to be working. I have this Angular template.

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="projectItem.DataType" >
  <option *ngFor="let item of getDataTypeList()" [ngValue]="item.Value">{{item.Name}}</option>
</select>
```

And I'm getting this error.

> Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'option'.

I already have BrowserModule imported in the app.module.ts.

```
app.module.ts
imports: [
  BrowserModule
]
```

And I already have CommonModule and FormsModule imported in the child module which is the module for that template/component.

```
app-list.module.ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      { path: '', component: AppListComponent }
    ]),
  ],
  exports: [
  ],
  declarations: [
  ],
  providers: [
  ]
})
```

So, I tried just importing only FormsModule in the child module, but it did not work, and I tried just importing only CommonModule, but it did not work.

And finally I tried without both CommonModule and FormsModule, and still did not work.

Why I think this is weird is that I have other child templates/components with both CommonModule and FormModule imported in their modules, and I have the exact same code and everything is working fine there.

I'm getting this error from only this particular child template/component.

Is there something I'm missing?

**EDIT**

Here is the component.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-app-list',
  templateUrl: './app-list.component.html',
})
export class AppListComponent {
  public projectItem: ProjectItem = new ProjectItem();
  getDataTypeList() {
    let nameValuePair: NameValuePair<string, DataType>[] = [];
    nameValuePair.push({ Name: "string", Value: DataType.String });
    nameValuePair.push({ Name: "Integer", Value: DataType.Int });
    return nameValuePair;
  }
}
export class ProjectItem {
  DataType: DataType;
}
export enum DataType { String = 1, Int = 2  }
export class NameValuePair<T1, T2> {
  Name: T1;
  Value: T2;
}
```

Comment: What does `getDataTypeList()` return? Make sure that there are no syntax / type mistakes in your html template. You can use VS Code with the angular language service to help spot those.

Comment: It returns an array of class which has only two properties, Name and Value. I already tried returning an empty array, but still no luck.. And if there is a syntax/type mistake, then I think I get some other errors. And like I said, I copied this code from another working component/template. So I think there is no syntax/type mistake.

Comment: Syntax seems fine, I can run it using stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-c4fe9q?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Try to import CommonModule and FormsModule in app.module.ts instead of child template component. @jongshin

Comment: OK. I just tried adding both modules in app.module.ts, but I'm still getting the same error..

Comment: How are you running your app? Is it with `ng serve`? If so when is the last time you killed it (ctrl+c) and restarted it?

Comment: Yes. I use ng serve and I already tried stopping and rerunning the service when I had this error hoping that would resolve the issue, but sadly I'm still getting the same error...

Comment: I just restarted my computer..but still no luck..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my god...it was a simple mistake.
I did not include AppListComponent in the declarations in app-list.module.ts.